# Create raster distance around a single point feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, distance, fuzzy-logic

Okay, so I'm relatively new to ArcMap and I'm trying to use the Fuzzy membership for suitability test. I have a single point feature class that I want to use for this analysis. I know that in order to be able to apply the Fuzzy membership you need to have a raster input. My question is how do I create a raster distance around my point on order to apply the fuzzy membership after? I tried all the Distance (Spatial Analyst) tools, but none seems to work for this situation.
Help is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your point data is in a projected coordinate system, then you can use the [Euclidean Distance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001p000000) tool.  This should produce a raster of distance that you can plug into your Fuzzy Membership tool.

Comment: Just checked and my point feature class in a projected coordinate system. When trying to run the Euclidean Distance tool this is the error I get: ERROR00o867 - Output cell size:contains invalid cell size or data set. and ERROR000581 - Invalid parameters. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: I created the point myself, so in the attribute table I would only have the OBJECTID and Shape fields. Would that be a problem?

Comment: artwork21, because this is a newbie question, I believe the OP would be grateful for more explicit directions, including some guidance on how to specify the output extent for the raster (because a default value will not be obtainable from an input feature class consisting of a single point).

Comment: I'm assuming that's the problem, since the Euclidean Direction works just fine for the other given point feature classes. I have no idea how to specify the output extent for the raster. Is there something I need to do when creating the feature class?
So sorry to be such a pain

Comment: Click on the "Environment" button at the bottom of the tool dialog and scroll to the raster options in the dialog that pops up.